# Generate unconditional simulations with same nugget, sill, and range

Tags: r, model, gstat, variogram, simulation

I am a newbie with gstat and unconditional simulations. As I understand, unconditional simulations should have the same nugget, psill, and range, but they do not (except nugget) when I use gstat in R. So how can I generate unconditional simulations with same nugget, psill, and range?

Here is how I generated unconditional simulations (I copied from [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/gstat.pdf) page 56):

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
xy <- expand.grid(1:100, 1:100)
names(xy) <- c('x', 'y')
sp::gridded(xy) = ~x+y
g.dummy <- gstat::gstat(formula=z~1, dummy=TRUE, beta=0, model=gstat::vgm(nugget=0.0001, 1, 'Gau', 15), nmax=10)
yy <- predict(g.dummy, xy, nsim=10)
```

Here is how I checked unconditional simulations and then see they have different psill and range (and different from the original/sample one - `gstat::vgm(nugget=0.0001, 1, 'Gau', 15)` ):

```
for (i in 1:10){
  var_name = paste0('sim', i)
  varrr <- gstat::variogram(object=yy@data[, var_name]~1, locations=yy[var_name])
  fit_varrr <- gstat::fit.variogram(object=varrr, model=gstat::vgm(nugget=0.0001, 1, 'Gau', 15))
  print(plot(varrr, model=fit_varrr))
  print(fit_varrr)
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the fitted variogram to be **exactly** nugget=0.0001, range=15, sill =1?

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

Comment: @Vince: I apologise, I have editted the question.

Comment: @Spacedman: Yes that is what I thought. Specifically, I expect to see the reproduced variograms (from unconditional simulations) have the same nugget, range, and sill. And as I stated in ```vgm``` I expect they should have nugget=0.0001, range=15, and sill =1.

Comment: It'll never be precise - its like expecting `mean(rnorm(100, mean=1.000, sd=1)` to be precisely 1.000.

Comment: @Spacedman: Thank you for your answer. I see what you mean. So is there still any other way that I can generate exactly the same those figures? Or at least as much close to those figures as possible? When I increase the number of simulations (50 for example), sills and ranges of some simulations are still very different. It's because I need them to be the same as the figures I stated as much as possible.

Comment: Practically no, especially since the variogram is fitted from a binned set of distance-variance averages, and changing the bins will likely change the precise fit of the model. There may be some way of repeatedly tweaking the generated values and fitting until you converge, but if you change the binning you'll get different answers.

Comment: @Spacedman: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide me with a bit more details about how I could modify the generated values and fit until I converge? I would like to give it a try.

Comment: Not sure I can, not without spending time on it. But basically what you've got is simulated data that is *close* to getting the fitted values you want, and if you did it a billion times you might get one data set that fits to four decimal places or something. But if you did 100, took the nearest one, added some noise values, fit, repeat etc you might be able to get there quicker. I really cant help any more unless I can actually see why you want to do this. Statistically speaking its an odd thing to do...

Comment: @Spacedman: Thank you very much for your reply. I am trying to generate different scenarios of a specific field using unconditional simulations. I understand your suggestion and am giving it a try.